# Insert 8 lines at the top with specified values into CSV file using VBA

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, export-to-csv

I have csv file which contains numbers and symbols in columns. I am exporting it into Access DB using VBA. The problem is that Access automatically trying to detect data type based on first 8 rows and first rows I have is numbers and then it ignores (gives error that can't convert data type actually) cells where I have symbols. Though I created table and specified all data types, still Access trying to convert it.
So I would like to know if there any way to "say" to Access not to convert data type and insert all records as Short Text?

If not, then I would like to add at the begining of the CSV file 8 lines with "Dummy" word in every cells.

Let's say I have table which looks like:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1     2    3
2     3    4
..   ..   ..
r1   r2   r3
```

and I would like to make it like

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
Dummy Dummy Dummy
Dummy Dummy Dummy
Dummy Dummy Dummy
Dummy Dummy Dummy
Dummy Dummy Dummy
Dummy Dummy Dummy
Dummy Dummy Dummy
Dummy Dummy Dummy
1     2    3
2     3    4
..   ..   ..
r1   r2   r3
```

Any way to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use a schema.ini?

Comment: Hi, no, I dont know what is this :(

Comment: you can search for schema.ini - there are tons of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use External Data import wizard to create an import specification. At the end of the wizard dialog, click Advanced to create specification. Reference the specification in DoCmd.TransferText method for subsequent imports.

Specification details are saved in hidden system tables MSysIMEXSpecs and MSysIMEXColumns. Can unhide system tables (can edit fields but that shouldn't be necessary) or use query:

```
SELECT MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecName, MSysIMEXColumns.DataType, MSysIMEXColumns.FieldName, MSysIMEXColumns.Start, MSysIMEXColumns.Width, MSysIMEXColumns.SkipColumn
FROM MSysIMEXColumns INNER JOIN MSysIMEXSpecs ON MSysIMEXColumns.SpecID = MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecID
ORDER BY MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecName, MSysIMEXColumns.Start, MSysIMEXColumns.Width;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but what it will change? I mean - I dont see there any field where I can mention data type or something like that. Most probably I missed something in your answer

Comment: I added ImportSpecification and tried to import data and it worked as a charm! I still didnt get why it works with this attribute, but it does the job! Thank you so much for pointing me into that and have a nice day!

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. The Import wizard dialog definitely offers an opportunity to set data type. The field storing it is in the query I provided.

Comment: No, at least in my version of Access there no possibility to set data type. All you can choose is File Format, Language, and Date, Time and Numbers format. Thats all.
Anyhow, even without specifying data type it is working somehow.

Comment: What version of Access? Yes, File Format and Language are on the Advanced dialog of the Import wizard. There is definitely a drop-down for selecting Data Type and text is an option. Data Type can also be defined on the main wizard dialog.

Comment: I added scrin to my question part, since I can't attach pics in comment.

Comment: Again, what version of Access? I use Access 2010. For me, there are two more columns in the Field Information section: Data Type and Indexed. These same options should also be available on one of the screens of the main wizard dialog.