# Import from Excel to MS Access ignores text entries from column that has both text and numbers

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import-from-excel

I have a function that automatically imports data from an Excel spreadsheet to an MS Access table. It works successfully with other imports, but I've just called it from a new import process and find that only numeric entries are being imported, even though the destination field is short text. I think that an assumption is being made based on the initial entries in this field, which are numeric.

Below is the function I'm using.

```
Public Function Import_Excel(strIMPORTTABLE As String, strFILE As String, strRANGE As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Run_SQL "Delete * From " & strIMPORTTABLE
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, strIMPORTTABLE, strFILE, True, strRANGE
    
    Import_Excel = True
    
EndRoutine:
    Exit Function
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Import_Excel = False
    Resume EndRoutine
End Function
```

The parameters I'm feeding it are the table name (which is correct), filename and path (also correct) and the range "Sheet1!A1:B50000", which is large enough for what I want. It's only two fields, the first is a unique identifier and the second is a text field that contains some numeric entries.

How can I make the import treat the second column as text?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Access import examines first few lines (8 I think) to determine data type. Import as text file and can create an import specification template that defines data types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73298068/insert-8-lines-at-the-top-with-specified-values-into-csv-file-using-vba/73301104?noredirect=1#comment129494945_73301104.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I thought it might be heading in this direction. Of course, if I'm going to automatically convert the spreadsheet to csv, I might as well just open the file and manipulate the data so that text entries appear near the top, then import as I would like to.

Comment: Could. Or could programmatically SaveAs csv.